# What are major and sub headings?

Tags: titles, chapters

What does a subheading mean in latex and what is a major heading?

Say your latex file has Chapter 1 called CHEMICAL TOOLS and in that chapter you have three titles (xxx, yyy, zzz):

**Chapter 1**

**CHEMICAL TOOLS**

**1.1 XXX**

**1.2 YYY**

**1.3 ZZZ**

Comment: they are just descriptive terms, not used in the latex documentation or code at all, so it's like asking how long is a piece of string, probably chapter headings are major headings and ones below that are not, but it's just a name.

Answer (score 3):

As David implied "It all depends". Depending on the particular LaTeX class there is a hierarchy of headings. The book and report classes provide `part`, `chapter`, `section`, `subsection`, `subsubsection`, `paragraph` and `subparagraph`. The article class has all of these except for `chapter`, while the memoir class adds `book` at the top of the book and report class hierarchies.

For the article class `section` is typically used for the major heading while `chapter` is usually the major heading in the other classes.